# Find the value of a variable in an equation involving the sum of two integrals

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I have the following expression:

$$\int_{0}^{LT} x^2 2\times10^{-4} e^{-2\times10^{-4} x} dx + \int_{LT}^{\infty} LT^2 2\times10^{-4} e^{-2\times10^{-4} x}dx = 7065080\\$$

I want to find the value of the variable LT, but, by solving the two integrals I ended up with:

$$2,5 \times 10^{11} -e^{-\frac{LT}{5\times10^3}}(5\times10^3LT^2 + 5 \times 10^7LT + 2,5 \times 10^{11} + 5 \times 10^3)=\dfrac{7065080}{2\times10^{-4}}$$

I can't manage to find a way to isolate the LT, i.e, the variable that I want to know the value.

I tried to just put some values and verified that $LT \approx 2000$ but I want to know a way to find the value analytically, is it possible?

Comment: With $LT$ both in and out of the exponent, there is surely no way to solve for it analytically.

Comment: @GerryMyerson. There is a mistake since $LT^2$ must disappear

Comment: @Claude, whether $LT^2$ disappears or not, there's still $LT$ both in and out of an exponent.

Comment: @GerryMyerson. What about Lambert function ? (my big love for 64+ years).

Comment: @Claude, the Lambert function is a wonderful thing; I'm not sure that it has yet been inducted into the Hall of Analytical Solutions.

Comment: I added a few details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if there is or not a mistake (the $L^2$ must disappear).

$$I_1=\frac 1{5000}\int_0^L x^2\,e^{-x/5000}\,dx=5\times10^7-e^{-L/5000}(5\times10^7+10^4L+L^2)$$
$$I_2=\frac {L^2}{5000}\int_L^\infty e^{-x/5000}\,dx=e^{-L/5000} L^2$$
$$f(L)=I_1+I_2-7065080=42934920-10^4\,e^{-L/5000} (L+5000)=0\tag1$$ The only explicit solution is given in terms of [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)
$$L=-5000 \left(1+W_{-1}\left(-\frac{1073373}{1250000 e}\right)\right)=3289.36\cdots$$

What is amuzing is that expanding $(1)$ as a Taylor series around  $L=0$

$$f(L)=-7065080+L^2-\frac{L^3}{7500}+\frac{L^4}{100000000}+O\left(L^5\right)$$

and using series reversion

$$L=t+\frac{t^2}{15000}+\frac{11 t^3}{1800000000}+O\left(t^4\right)\quad \text{where} \quad t=\sqrt{f(L)+7065080}$$ Since we want $f(L)=0$, then the *approximation*
$$L\sim  \frac{176627}{375} +\frac{46942897}{2250000}\sqrt{\frac{176627}{10}}=3243.79\cdots$$

**Details**

$$42934920-10^4\,e^{-L/5000} (L+5000)=0$$ Let $L=5000(x-1)$ to make
$$42934920-5\times 10^7\, e\,x\, e^{-x} =0 \implies x\, e^{-x} =\frac{1073373}{1250000\,e}\implies x=-W_{-1}\left(-\frac{1073373}{1250000 \,e}\right)$$

The argument is quite small $(t=\sim -0.3159)$. Have a look at [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1003.1628); it gives approximations (the Wikipedia page also).

Comment: Thank you! I'm struggling to find how you found the Lambert Function in the expression. I've spent the whole day trying to understand the W lambert function and managed to understand that I have to find an expression like $xe^x$ and $W(xe^x) = x$, but I can't find a way to relate this with the expression that you got.

Comment: $10^4e^{-L/5000}(L+5000)$ is "an expression like $xe^x$", just let $L=x-5000$ and push a few constant multipliers to the other side of the equation.

Comment: Yes, I think I didn't manage to see the expression, thanks for clarifying it. This W Lambert Function seems very powerful, I'm very happy to understand it now.

Comment: @Shinobu. It is a very interesting function; if you type *Lambert* on the search bar of the site, there are 3833 entries. Did you notice that the first term of Taylor series already gives $L=\sqrt{ 7065080}=2658.02$ ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici. Now, I'm having some trouble understanding the series reversion process, I watched some videos on youtube and some questions about this topic here on StackExchange, but I didn't understand the process that lead you to make  $t=\sqrt{f(L) + 65080}$. Sorry if these are silly questions, I'm new to this topic.